# micro optimisation using and operator

Tags: c++, c, optimization

Suppose this situation, you have a function that return void and the method is mostly gonna be the only statement of a if

```
if(condition)
    someVoidMethod();
```

Since certain language will not continue the evaluation of a boolean expression of concatenated and's if any of them return false. We are wondering what are the optimization implied by changing the return type to int (or bool/boolean) and writing this instead

```
condition && someIntMethod();
```

without any assignation.

We understand that programmers shouldn't focus in micro-optimization but it's really just for academic purpose.

Comment: Try both variants, and see the generated assembly code. Both without and with optimizations. My guess? The compiler, when optimizing, will probably generate the same code for both alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler will generate the same code for both alternatives with any reasonable level of optimization. The logic behind both statements is exactly the same, because `&&` produces a branching behavior in both C and C++ for short-circuiting.

I verified this using two programs:

Program 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo() {printf("foo\n");}
int main() {
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i); // Prevent from optimizing out the "if"
    if (i) foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Program 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo() {printf("foo\n");}
int main() {
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i); // Prevent from optimizing out the "if"
    i && foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled both programs on my mac with -O3 level <sup>*</sup>, and compared the output:

```
gcc -c -O3 a.c
gcc -c -O3 b.c
cmp a.o b.o
```

`cmp` produced no output, so the files were identical. Compiling without -O3 flag produced different outputs.

---

<sup>*</sup> `gcc --version` command prints

> `Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang 500.2.79) (based on llvm 3.3svn)`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Did you also try when the body of `foo` isn't visible at the point of call?

Comment: @MarkB I tried that out as well, and saw no change: both programs produced the same output.

Comment: For more information on short-circuit evaluation the wikipedia article on it is useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Which version of gcc did you use? I'm unable to replicate the identical object files using your code and commands with gcc 4.5.

Comment: @MarkB I am seeing these results on my mac, with `gcc --version` printing `Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang 500.2.79) (based on llvm 3.3svn)`

Answer (score 1):

It would take a smarter compiler to figure out that it can ignore the return value from `someIntMethod` (although I suspect most compilers would do so). But more seriously if the function isn't `inline` it would *have* to take extra cycles to pass the value back even if it's going to be discarded, so the first is possibly more efficient.

That said the only way to know for sure is to compile both with your compiler and options consistent with a release build and see what assembly it generates.

Comment: Discarding the return value in the statement itself is easy, but maybe difficult for `someIntMethod` if it isn't inlined. So the operator `&&` version could well turn out slower.

Comment: As dasblinkenlight has pointed out, C and C++ both implement short circuit behavior for &&, therefore _if and only if_ 'condition' is true then 'someIntMethod()' will be evaluated. This makes the above functionally equivalent and should be optimized in the same fashion (compiler implementation will of course be allowed to vary for optimization, but the short circuit behavior will always remain).